# Losing data when importing database with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, ubuntu

I'm trying to import a SQL database with mysql but not all of the rows are imported.

I'm using Ubuntu 17, mysql Ver 14.14, Distrib 5.7.26. First, I'm opening mysql with "mysql -u root -p", then "use db;", then "source [fullpath]/db.sql". Using this I get error message:

```
ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected
```

Unfortunately, I check if all tables are imported with "show tables;" and only 2 of 5 tables are imported. Furthermore, not all rows from second table are imported. I'm sure that there must be 5 tables and X number of rows.

To prevent this I used this command:

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost -D db --binary-mode -o < [fullpath]/db.sql
```

But it gives me "ERROR at line 144: Unknown command '\�'."

I've also tried converting database to utf-8 format with this command:

```
sudo iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 db.sql > db_utf8.sql
```

Then tried using "source" command for "db_utf8.sql" but got this error:

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    42
Current database: db

ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    43
Current database: db

ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
```

Please, does someone know what to do.

My coworkers are using the same file and everything is okay for them so maybe I'm not using the correct commands.

Edit: In some questions there are tips about (un)ziping the file but this one was never ziped or unziped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now. I'm lucky that I have a coworker that tried the same and everything was okay. So I mysqldump'ed the database from that computer, moved the .sql file to my computer and tried to import this dumped file. Now everything works fine.